# (C#) Class member initializing thread-safety issue

Tags: c#, static, thread-safety

Comparing 2 ways of class property defenition (A & B):

```
// implemention A
public class Cache {
    private object m_syncRoot = null;
    public object SyncRoot {
        get {
            if (m_syncRoot == null) {
                Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref m_syncRoot, new object(), null);            
            }
            return m_syncRoot;
        }
    }
}
```

AND

```
// implemention B.
public class Cache {
    public object SyncRoot { get; } = new object(); // in C# 6.0
}
```

And finally some where uses cache:

```
static Cache MyCache = new Cache(); //  I don't know if this kind of declaration is thread-safe either
lock (MyCache.SyncRoot) {
    ....
}
```

Question:

Since "Cache" will be used as static instance, are both "SyncRoot" creations in [A] & [B] thread-safe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, both of the two creation are thread-safe. The difference is in implementation `B`, the `SyncRoot` object is created when the `Cache` instance is created. And in `A`, `SyncRoot` is created when it is accessed.